# Вертикальное расположение текста

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css

Кто знает как расположить текст вот так

[image: img]

кроссбраузерно, а именно нужно для ie8 и ниже.

Comment: картинкой?

Comment: [Как-то так](http://yandex.ru/yandsearch?text=html+css+%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9+%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82).

Comment: Капитан очевидность)), а по делу есть что-нить, в нете много хлама не нужного, мне нужно сделать всё красиво без всякого js и картинок, можно ли как-то это сделать

Comment: Ну народ ленивый пошёл... [Первая же ссылка по моей ссылке](http://www.xiper.net/collect/html-and-css-tricks/typographics/vertical-text.html)

Comment: минус ТС за ленивость :)

Comment: Вы наверное слепые, мне нужно повернуть не вправо а влево!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Это что, шутка такая? Поверни влево, раз надо.

Comment: ну вы вообщееееееее, надо чтобы работало в IE8 и ниже, то-ли вы реально не читаете полностью, то-ли я чего-то не допанимаю, если так всё просто так напишите стили, как написал человек ниже(правда в ie8 у него не работает как мне надо), и не стройте из себя умных!!!

Comment: @Karalahti Я вот прочитал все. и напишу так "Сделай все сам". Тебе правильно написали - лентяй.

Леплю минус и тревогу  "Работа за автора"

Comment: ок скиньте скрин как вы сделали, как получилось в итоге.
потому что вашими методами получается не как у меня на скрине И именно чтобы в ie8 и ниже работало!!!!!!1

Comment: А что получается то? Пишите -- поправим, либо платите деньги за работу. что за детсад?!?! :)

зыж и не надо столько !!!! ставить. Вам тут ничем не обязаны.

Comment: Картинкой я сделал но ищу решение без картинки

Comment: http://i47.fastpic.ru/big/2013/0412/df/fb4ee27351c4dafe87fb932e9fcfabdf.jpg ну допустим у меня в 7ом нормально работает пример по ссылке @klopp .

Answer (score 3):

```
.rotate {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);

  /* also accepts left, right, top, bottom coordinates; not required, but a good idea for styling */
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -o-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;

  /* Should be unset in IE9+ I think. */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
}
```